# How do I use the Deezer Api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deezer

I'm trying to use the deezer api to look up artists and display their name and image using Jquery. Here's my code:

```
 $.getJSON('http://api.deezer.com/search/artists?q='+q+'',
    function(data) {
      $("#artists").empty();
      $.each(data, function(i,item){

var y=item.picture;

var z=x+y;

        $("#artists").append("<div id='card_artist'><div id='cardimg' style='background-image: url("+ z +");'></div><div id='artistname' class='jtextfill'><span>" + item.name + "<span></div></div>");
   }); 
});
```

but it just won't work. The code seems fine, but it keeps throwing up this error message, which I haven't a clue about or how to fix:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.deezer.com/search/artists?q=whatever. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown because your browser is blocking the request. Because you execute this from javascript from your own site or maybe localhost, you do a cross-site request by calling a different url (the Deezer url). There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. Try the following 'hack' with jsonp:

   ```
   // Using YQL and JSONP
   $.ajax({
       url: "http://api.deezer.com/search/artists?q="+q,

       // the name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
       jsonp: "callback",

       // tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
       dataType: "jsonp",

       // tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
       data: {
           format: "json"
       },

       // work with the response
       success: function( response ) {
            $("#artists").empty();
            $.each(data, function(i,item){

                var y=item.picture;

                var z=x+y;

                $("#artists").append("<div id='card_artist'><div id='cardimg' style='background-image: url("+ z +");'></div><div id='artistname' class='jtextfill'><span>" + item.name + "<span></div></div>");

            }
   });
   ```

   Source: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Or 2. You route the request through your own server.
With a server side language like php you do the request to the Deezer Api, and with jQuery you call that php page.

Comment: Ah!!! *facepalm* I was going about it the wrong way... I totally forgot about JSONP, thank you for clearing that up!