# Angular 2 , No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: api, http, angular, cors, deezer

we have angular 2 application and we are trying to use Deezer API, but when I try to send GET request to Deezer I get the given error. I have tried lots of solution like using jsonp and adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : ' * ' to .htaccess, but none of them was helpful. I have attached the function that I am using in service.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q=emin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "www.example.net" is therefore not allowed access.**

```
searchFromDeezer() {
  let url = 'https://api.deezer.com/search/' + this.search_type + '?q=' + this.search_value + '';
  return this._http.get(url).map(res=>res.json())
}
```

How I have used jsonp:

```
like below.

searchFromDeezer() {
  let url = 'https://api.deezer.com/search/' + this.search_type + '?q=' + this.search_value + '?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK';
  return this._jsonp.get(url).map(res=>res.json())
}
```

Comment: use JSONP see the link below : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2)

Comment: As I mentioned I already have used it, I get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
vendor.bundle.js:59960 
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185964/how-do-i-use-the-deezer-api/23186126#23186126

Comment: Guys, I have used jsonp , I am updating the code how I did it

Comment: The server needs to handle the OPTIONS verb and return HTTP OK

Comment: Problem have no relation to Angular. It is native browser behaviour.

Comment: @pixelbits We'll try this one

Comment: @Pavel So, what is the solution?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I was trying to use jsonp but was getting error, problem has been fixed after adding
*'&output=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK'*  to my link.